# Android Fragment Manager (Support), restoring state AND order after orientation change

Tags: android, android-fragments, screen-orientation

Been searching most of the day today on an effective way to do this. I feel that part of my issue is my architecture, but I'm well beyond patching that, and I definitely have to support landscape orientation.

My app heavily uses fragments. I'm supporting 2.2 and up. I have ~ 11 fragments in use total. Two of which, make up a static header and footer. Those are easy to work with.

My real issue is what to do to properly restore the state of a fragment (say registration, with partially filled forms) after savedInstanceState() happens. This easy enough when my stack only contains 1 item. That item by default is re-drawn and I can handle it.

What I'm having difficulty with is when I have multiple items in the stack when I rotate. My stack still holds these fragments, but they are detached, and I can't intelligently re-attach them without introducing spaghetti relationship checks all over the place.

If you can help me get at least that far, is it possible to even make use of the savedstate bundle at that point?

Been struggling with this all day. I really enjoyed working fragments until now.

Please don't mention:

```
 android:configChanges="orientation">
```

It's not working for me  / not applicable.